# Issue with height of toggled 2nd level nested tables in tabulator

Tags: jquery, tabulator

I'm creating a toggled nested table within a nested table using tabulator.

Everything working great except for one thing.

When the 2nd nested table is toggled off the height of the nesting table is not updated.

I tried setting the height of the holders objects to auto but it didn't work.

This is my code

```
    var table1 = new Tabulator("#table1", {
        height:"100%",
        columnHeaderVertAlign:"bottom", //align header contents to bottom of cell
        layout:"fitdataStreach",        
        selectable: true,
        data:tabledata,
        columns:[
            {formatter:"handle", width:10, align:"center", headerSort:false, cellClick:function(e, row, formatterParams){
                const id = row.getData().id;
                $(".subTable"+id).toggle();table1.height = "100%";}

            },
            {title:"Job Name", field:"jobname", sorter:"string", headerFilter:"input"},
            {title:"Source", field:"src", headerFilter:"input"},
            {title:"Destination", field:"dst", headerFilter:"input"},
            {//create column group
                title:"Baseline",
                columns:[
                    {title:"Status", field:"baselinestatus",formatter:function(cell, formatterParams){
                            var value = cell.getValue();
                            if(value == "failed"){
                                return "<span style='color:red; font-weight:bold;'>" + value + "</span>";
                            }else if(value == "running" || value == "complete"){
                                return "<span style='color:green; font-weight:bold;'>" + value + "</span>";
                            }else if(value == "pending"){
                                return "<span style='color:orange; font-weight:bold;'>" + value + "</span>";                                
                            }else{
                                return value;
                            }
                        }
                    }, 
                    {title:"Duration", field:"baselinetime"},
                    {title:"Sent", field:"baselinesentshort"},
                ],
            },
            {//create column group
                title:"Lst Sync",
                columns:[
                    {title:"Status", field:"syncstatus", formatter:function(cell, formatterParams){
                            var value = cell.getValue();
                            if(value == "failed"){
                                return "<span style='color:red; font-weight:bold;'>" + value + "</span>";
                            }else if(value == "running" || value == "complete"){
                                return "<span style='color:green; font-weight:bold;'>" + value + "</span>";
                            }else if(value == "pending"){
                                return "<span style='color:orange; font-weight:bold;'>" + value + "</span>";                                                                
                            }else if(value == "idle"){
                                return "<span style='color:green; font-weight:bold;'>" + value + "</span>";                                
                            }else{
                                return value;
                            }
                        }
                    }, 
                    {title:"Next Schedule", field:"syncsched", formatter:function(cell, formatterParams){
                            var value = cell.getValue();
                            if(value == "-" || value == "paused"){
                                return "<span style='color:orange; font-weight:bold;'>" + value + "</span>";                                         
                            }else{
                                return "<span style='color:green; font-weight:bold;'>" + value + "</span>";  
                            }
                        }
                    },
                    {title:"Duration", field:"synctime"},
                    {title:"Sent", field:"syncsentshort"},
                    {title:"Count", field:"synccounter"},
                ],
            },
            {//create column group
                title:"Last Verify",
                columns:[
                    {title:"Status", field:"verifystatus", formatter:function(cell, formatterParams){
                            var value = cell.getValue();
                            if(value == "failed" || value == "diff"){
                                return "<span style='color:red; font-weight:bold;'>" + value + "</span>";
                            }else if(value == "running" || value == "complete" || value == "equal"){
                                return "<span style='color:green; font-weight:bold;'>" + value + "</span>";
                            }else if(value == "pending"){
                                return "<span style='color:orange; font-weight:bold;'>" + value + "</span>";                                                                
                            }else{
                                return value;
                            }
                        }
                    }, 
                    {title:"Start Time", field:"verifystarttime"}, 
                    {title:"Ratio", field:"verifyratio"},
                    {title:"Count", field:"verifycounter"},
                ],
            },   

        ],
        rowFormatter:function(row) {
            //create and style holder elements
            var holderEl = document.createElement("div");
            var tableEl = document.createElement("div");

            const id = row.getData().id;

            holderEl.style.boxSizing = "border-box";
            holderEl.style.padding = "10px 10px 10px 10px";
            holderEl.style.borderTop = "1px solid #333";
            holderEl.style.borderBotom = "1px solid #333";
            holderEl.style.background = "#ddd";
            holderEl.style.display = "none";
            holderEl.setAttribute('class', "subTable" + id + "");


            tableEl.style.border = "1px solid #333";
            tableEl.style.display = "none";
            tableEl.setAttribute('class', "subTable" + id + "");


            holderEl.appendChild(tableEl);

            row.getElement().appendChild(holderEl);

            var subTable = new Tabulator(tableEl, {
                layout:"fitColumns",        
                selectable: true,
                columnHeaderVertAlign:"bottom", //align header contents to bottom of cell
                //layout:"fitData",                       
                data:row.getData().verboseDetails,
                columns:[
                    {formatter:"handle", width:10, align:"center", headerSort:false, cellClick:function(e, row, formatterParams){
                        const id = row.getData().id;
                        $(".logTable"+id).toggle();table1.height = "100%";}

                    },                
                    {title:"Phase",      field:"phase"},
                    {title:"Start Time", field:"starttime", sorter:"datetime", sorterParams:{format:"YYYY-MM-DD hh:mm:ss",},},
                    {title:"End Time",   field:"endtime"},
                    {title:"Duration",   field:"duration"},
                    {title:"Scanned",    field:"scanned"},
                    {title:"Reviewed",   field:"reviewed"},
                    {title:"Copied",     field:"copied"},
                    {title:"Modified",   field:"modified"},                 
                ], 
                rowFormatter:function(row) {
                    //create and style holder elements
                    var holderEl1 = document.createElement("div");
                    var tableEl1 = document.createElement("div");

                    const id = row.getData().id;

                    holderEl1.style.boxSizing = "border-box";
                    holderEl1.style.padding = "10px 10px 10px 10px";
                    holderEl1.style.borderTop = "1px solid #333";
                    holderEl1.style.borderBotom = "1px solid #333";
                    holderEl1.style.background = "#ddd";
                    holderEl1.style.display = "none";
                    holderEl1.setAttribute('class', "logTable" + id + "");

                    tableEl1.style.border = "1px solid #333";
                    tableEl1.style.display = "none";
                    tableEl1.setAttribute('class', "logTable" + id + "");

                    holderEl1.appendChild(tableEl1);

                    row.getElement().appendChild(holderEl1);

                    var logTable = new Tabulator(tableEl1, {
                        layout:"fitColumns",         
                        data:row.getData().logsdata,
                        columns:[

                            {title:"STDERR Content", field:"stderrlogcontent",formatter:"link", formatterParams:{ urlField: "stderrurl", target:"_blank",}, headerSort:false},
                            {title:"STDOUT Content", field:"stdoutlogcontent",formatter:"link", formatterParams:{ urlField: "stdouturl", target:"_blank",}, headerSort:false},

                        ],   
                    });                 
                },
            });        
        },
    });
```

Comment: Welcome to SO! You might take the [Tour](https://stackoverflow.com/tour) and you should (re-)read the help topic [How to Ask](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/how-to-ask) to get a feeling on how to contribute. You should provide a minimal, complete and reproducible example ([MCRE](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example)) of your code as yours is hard to read. Keep in mind that creating an MCRE often helps to identify any problems by yourself and you will learn to better understand your code. Also: add any errors you get or your actual result vs. your expected result.

Answer (score 0):

If you add some example data for the `tableData` variable, then I can create an example and test it for you.  But, I think that your issue is you should use `table.setHeight('100%')` instead of `table.height = 100%`.  Then, you may also need to call `table.redraw()` as well.

Look at the Table Resizing section for some more information.
http://tabulator.info/docs/4.6/layout#virtual-dom-redraw

Comment: Thanks for the help. This is the complete file: https://drive.google.com/open?id=1aM488DgJnVMmk00cE5Cfb8SFxuU5iJhG